# Is there a way to save the rendered node locations obtained by the layout algorithm?

Tags: vis.js, pyvis

When I open the saved HTML network file, it takes quite some time to load my network of a few thousand nodes. Would it be possible to save the node locations to avoid running the network layout algorithm whenever I open the file?

Comment: Did you manage to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a manual solution, but it should work - it is about getting the node locations once they are loaded in your browser through javascript and then copy the locations to the html file.

See https://holzsec.github.io/rfcview/graphs/all_static.html

1. Render Graph in Browser => F12 Console

```
    network.storePositions();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.nodes.get()))
```

Copy output to clipboard

2. Edit html file/ cp html to version_static.html

- Comment out loadbar div
- Comment out loadbar js/css (optional)
- Set physics options to false

"physics": {
"enabled": false,
"repulsion": {

- goto nodes = and copy output from 1) to the vis.DataSet array

Save and done!
(Happy to collaborate on some sort of automation for this)